# How to subtract the time based on the timezone offset

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, timezone-offset

I tried looking for an answer but could not find a particular answer which does with Timezone offset. Hence, posting the same really sorry if there are any answer present already.

I have a requirement in the project where I need to convert the time to `UTC` or `GMT` based on the time specified by the user and timezone offset value provided by the user. Basically, the user provides his local time and timezone offset value according to his local time. I need to convert that into UTC/GMT time.

I am using the Node.js and following is the data which is available in the Node.js Backend:

```
Time: 2020-11-05T15:00:00.000Z
Timezone offset value: +02:00
```

As the timezone offset value is +02:00 I need to subtract it from the time to convert it into the UTC format. so I can get the time as: `2020-11-05T13:00:00.000Z`. I using the `moment-js` as well. Can someone please help me how can achieve this using the Node.js or using the Moment.js?

Comment: I think Moment js is now deprecated, or perhaps that's the wrong word: consider using alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the offset takes daylight saving time into account you should be able to do:

```
const the_date = '2020-11-05T15:00:00.000';
const offset = 2;
const utc_time = moment.utc(the_date).subtract(offset, 'hours');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response :)
I tried one more method that also worked.

Comment: This doesn't adjust for offset, nor does it take daylight saving time into account.  It creates a UTC moment that is two hours earlier than the UTC time given.  You started with 15:00 UTC, you ended with 13:00 UTC.

Comment: As stated in the answer, I assumed DST was "included" in the `offset`. Further more, `the_date` in the answer is not UTC. I made the assumption that the OP accidentally gave the time in UTC.

Answer (score 1):

After some more research and trying, I was able to convert it. Posting the answer in addition to Christians response (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64701083/7584240) so if anyone is looking for the answer they will have another option:

```
var moment      =   require('moment');
var time        =   "2020-11-05T15:00:00.000Z";
var timeoffset  =   "+02:00";
    time        =   moment.utc(time).local().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:SS.000');
    time        =   moment(time, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000').subtract(timeoffset).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000') + 'Z';
```

Comment: This approach is not recommended.  You're creating a string just to parse it again (always a bad idea), and you're introducing local time for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear which way you are trying to convert.  If you are converting from UTC to a fixed offset, you can use the [`utcOffset`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/) function, like this:

```
const m = moment.utc('2020-11-05T15:00:00.000Z').utcOffset('+02:00');
m.format();  //=> "2020-11-05T17:00:00+02:00"
```

Or - if you were trying to convert *from* +02:00, then you would include that offset in the input instead of the `Z` (Z means UTC).  You would then just call the `utc` function, like this:

```
const m = moment('2020-11-05T15:00:00.000+02:00').utc();
m.format();  //=> "2020-11-05T13:00:00Z"
```

*However* you should be aware that an offset is not the same as a time zone.  A time zone can have more than one offset, one of which will apply at a given point in time.  Those offsets can change due to daylight saving time and for changes in standard time.  Thus, asking a user to pick "his timezone offset value according to his local time" is problematic - as you may be applying that offset to the wrong point in time.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for further details.

You should also understand [Moment's project status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/), and possibly choose a different library.